How do I improve the sync performance of fastapi?
I want to get a better sync performance on fastapi endpoint. So far I can only get good performance when using async endpoint, but hit a bottleneck on sync endpoint.
Server Code
@app.get("/sync/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    time.sleep(1)
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}

@app.get("/async/{item_id}")
async def aread_item(item_id: int, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}

Benchmark Results
Running with fastapi run benchmark/main.py



Endpoint
Command
Requests per second (mean)




Async
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 "http://localhost:8000/async/31"
1496.38 [#/sec]


Sync
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 "http://localhost:8000/sync/31"
39.48 [#/sec]



Running with poetry run gunicorn benchmark.main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker



Endpoint
Command
Requests per second (mean)




Async
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 "http://localhost:8000/async/31"
3462.74 [#/sec]


Sync
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 "http://localhost:8000/sync/31"
105.77 [#/sec]



Running with poetry run gunicorn benchmark.main:app --workers 12 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker



Endpoint
Command
Requests per second (mean)




Async
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 "http://localhost:8000/async/31"
7593.36 [#/sec]


Sync
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 "http://localhost:8000/sync/31"
155.80 [#/sec]



Running with uvicorn benchmark.main:app --workers 12 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000



Endpoint
Command
Requests per second (mean)




Async
ab -c 10000 -n 100000 "http://localhost:8000/async/31"
7507.83 [#/sec]




sleep(1) doesn't represent the typical load of a REST call at all.

You've effectively discovered why async is a thing - it allows more efficient handling of connections when your process spends most of its time waiting (usually for io). When using sync, you're effectively scaling by using the workers parameter, combined with the standard threadpool size of 40 (from anyio which Starlette uses). You can see this from your first test where you get 40 req/s. But you'll have to test with a real life scenario and not a synthetic one which is especially well-suited to async.

Does this answer your question?
